# Iot Board Disconnects from MQTT protocol after first attempt

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, tls1.2, mbed

I am currently using the AT&T IoT Starter kit, equipped with FRDM-K64F development board w/ cellular shield attached. I am using this kit to subscribe to a MQTT protocol via AWS and I am running into some issues. I successfully connect the first time, but then after a few seconds the connection is lost and when it reconnects it will either reconnect successfully or give me the following error (see link below)

**Error1**

[image: Error1]

After it attempts to reconnect a few times the following error shows up, which I think means there is no more RAM on the board and as a result there is no input.(see link below)

**Error2**

[image: Error2]

Can someone please help me figure why it cannot maintain a connection? It says tls handshake error, could it be a issue with the certificates? I'm at a loss.

EDIT: Looks like the pictures don't work so here are the errors

1.Error: failed

```
   !mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned 0x1.
```

The other two errors it gives after attempting connection a few times is

2.Error: failed

```
   !mbedtls_ssl_setup returned 0x7f00
```

and

3.Error: failed

```
   !mbedtls_ssl_write returned 0x7100
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of error messages, they are hard to read and not searchable.. Post the actual text and use the tool bar to format it.

Comment: It's not clear from the logs whether the initial connection was successful. You need to configure AWS IoT with your certificate and a policy for the TLS connection to succeed.

Comment: @blt
So sometimes the connection is successful on the first try and sometimes it is not. It will attempt to reconnect and sometimes it will result in a successful connect or it does not. After a few seconds it disconnects and goes into a cycle of attempting to reconnect until it finally gives the last two errors.